# Using DifferentialEquations package in Julia to solve matrix ODE

Tags: matrix, julia, ode, differentialequations.jl

I would like to solve:

[\mathbf{M} \ddot{ \mathbf{U} }+ \mathbf{C} \dot{ \mathbf{U} }+ \mathbf{K} \mathbf{U} = \mathbf{P}(t)]

Or, in state-space form:

[\dot{\mathbf{Y}}=f(\mathbf{Y},t)]

where:

[\mathbf{Y} = \left[ \begin{array}{ c} \mathbf{U} \ \dot{ \mathbf{U} \end{array} \right] ]

and:

[f( \mathbf{Y} ,t)= \left[ \begin{array}{ c} \dot{ \mathbf{U} }\ \mathbf{M}^{-1} \mathbf{P} (t)- \mathbf{M} ^{-1} \mathbf{C} \dot{ \mathbf{U} }- \mathbf{M} ^{-1} \mathbf{K} \mathbf{U} \end{array} \right] ]

I tried the following code in Julia, using

\mathbf{M} = \left[ \begin{array}{ cc} 2&0\ 0&1 \end{array} \right];

\mathbf{C} = \left[ \begin{array}{ cc} 0&0\ 0& 0 \end{array} \right];

\mathbf{K} = \left[ \begin{array}{ cc} 96&-32\ -32& 32 \end{array} \right];

\mathbf{P} (t)= \left[ \begin{array}{ c} 10\ 10 \end{array} \right]

.

```
using DifferentialEquations
function eq(t,u,du)
    v=reshape([u...],Int(length(u)/2),2)
    du=reshape([v[:,2];-[10;10]-M\C*v[:,2]-M\K*v[:,1]],length(u))
end
u0=[0;0;0;0];
tspan=(0.0,10.0);
prob=ODEProblem(eq,u0,tspan)
sol=solve(prob)
```

But running these lines of code results to this error:

```
ERROR: InexactError()
```

I am using Julia ver. 0.5.2.

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Your explicit equation should read `U''=M^(-1)*(P(t)-C*U'-K*U)`. In your version the `M^(-1)` before `P(t)` is missing, both in the transformed equations and in the code. -- You should have defined `Y`, not `\dot Y` as `[U;U']`.

Comment: Thank you for showing me my mistakes.

Comment: For your math editing also explore the `amslatex` package, where you can find the `bmatrix` environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that DifferentialEquations.jl respects your input type.

```
u0=[0;0;0;0];
```

This is an array of integers, and so this means that your problem will be evolving an array of integers. In the first step, it finds out that it the calculation returns floating point numbers, and so it doesn't know what to make `u` because you said it had to be an array of integers. The fix for that is to say that your problem is on floating point numbers:

```
u0=[0.0;0.0;0.0;0.0];
```

Now that evolves correctly.

But let's go another step. DifferentialEquations.jl respects your input type, so DifferentialEquations.jl will make it into a problem on matrices just by making the initial condition a matrix. No reshaping is necessary if you make `u0` a matrix:

```
u0=[0.0 0.0
    0.0 0.0]
```

Once you do that, you just write an equation which directly works on matrices. Example:

```
using DifferentialEquations
M = 1
K = 1
C = 1
function eq(t,u,du)
  du .= u[:,2] .- 10 - M./C.*u[:,2] - M.\K.*u[:,1]
end
u0=[0.0 0.0
    0.0 0.0]
tspan=(0.0,10.0);
prob=ODEProblem(eq,u0,tspan)
sol=solve(prob)
```

I'm not sure I got the equation you were trying to solve correct because it's extremely hard to read, but that should get you very close to what you want.

Comment: Great. Thank you so much. I am impressed by the unique features of DifferentialEquations package.

Comment: Sorry, could you please give another example with matrices M, C, K (not scalars as used in your previous example).

Comment: It's the same if you make `M`, `C`, and `K` matrices.  All that needs to be true is you have to update the values of `du`. Any mathematical statement that does that is valid.

Comment: I tried the following codes, but the results sol seems to be zeros for all values of t. Am I wrong somewhere here?

`function eq(t,u,du);
       v=reshape([u...],Int(length(u)/2),2);
       du=reshape([v[:,2]; -M^(-1)*([10;10]-C*v[:,2]-K*v[:,1])],length(u));
end;
M=[2.0 0.0; 0.0 1.0];
C=[0.0  0.0; 0.0 0.0];
K=[96.0 -32.0; -32.0  32.0];
u0=[0.0 ;0.0; 0.0; 0.0];
tspan=(0.0, 10.0);
prob=ODEProblem(eq,u0,tspan);
sol=solve(prob);`

Comment: You're not updating `du`, you're creating a new `du`. Notice that my code used `.=` instead of `=`. You should write it so you're updating `du` instead of replacing it. Or you can use the function signature `eq(t,u)` and return the array for the update (the MATLAB style), though this will take a hit to performance.

Comment: Even when I correct my code to update `du`, I still got zero `sol` for all `t`. Am I wrong somewhere?

`function eq(t,u,du);
       v =reshape([u...],Int(length(u)/2),2);
       du .=reshape([v[:,2]; M^(-1)*([10;10]-C*v[:,2]-K*v[:,1])],length(u));
end;
M=[2.0 0.0; 0.0 1.0];
C=[0.0  0.0; 0.0 0.0];
K=[96.0 -32.0; -32.0  32.0];
u0=[0.0 ;0.0; 0.0; 0.0];
tspan=(0.0, 10.0);
prob=ODEProblem(eq,u0,tspan);
sol=solve(prob);`

Comment: And here is my another attempt. This times, I got an error.

`function eq(t,u,du)
          du .=[u[:,2]; M^(-1)*([10;10]-C*u[:,2]-K*u[:,1])];
end;
M=[2.0 0.0; 0.0 1.0];
C=[0.0  0.0; 0.0 0.0];
K=[96.0 -32.0; -32.0  32.0];
u0=[0.0  0.0; 0.0  0.0];
tspan=(0.0, 10.0);
prob=ODEProblem(eq,u0,tspan);
sol=solve(prob);`

Comment: The matrix you're making doesn't look like it makes sense: the first row has a column vector, and the second row has a  column vector? You likely meant to write that differently. Come to the chatroom to sort this out: https://gitter.im/JuliaDiffEq/Lobby